# getting error with zend 2 and DateTime object

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying get current date in zend 2 , I use this code to get current date and time

$datetime = new DateTime();

But it throw an error  "Class 'Application\Controller\DateTime' not found in  C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php on line 26

how can I fix this bug? thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$datetime = new \DateTime("now");
```

or if you dont like the backslash include

```
use DateTime;
```

at the start of your file and then the format is;

```
$datetime = new DateTime("now");
```

Comment: You trying to use DateTime object without specifying the namespace, so it was looking locally, hence the error... "Class 'Application\Controller\DateTime' not found